# How to connect Jupyter Notebook in VS Code to R Studio Connect

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rsconnect

From my understanding, I should be able to use R Studio connect in VS Code Editor once I've downloaded the python extension and the rsconnect-python package. Then when I try to save the server information, I get syntax errors. Is there a specific place that I need to put the CLI? I tried to put it in the terminal as well but rsconnect is not recognized.

Here is what I tried:

```
rsconnect add \
    --api-key my-api-key \
    --server https://connect.example.org:3939 \
    --name myserver
```

I get syntax error when I run in the .py file. Then when I try to run it in the terminal using Python, it does not recognize rsconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is not currently implemented in vscode. You can use jupyter notebook to [connect](https://docs.rstudio.com/how-to-guides/rsc/publish-jupyter-notebook/).

You can also request related functions in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues), and developers will provide the function for this in the future。